# What is a synonym for "handling someone," like some sales people do, instead of doing what is requested?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a verb that describes the act of dealing with someone on a superficially polite and considerate way without actually intending to do what is being requested. This kind of thing might happen when you call for technical support or deal with customer service. Instead of directly answering questions or attending to the concern, the person might, say, ask irrelevant questions, ignore or repeatedly "misremember" the customer's questions, offer some stock phrase or advice, etc.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Paying lip service**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+lip+service) to insincerely agree with an idea or notion to someone's face (usually for expediency).

Also see [**blowing smoke up someone's ass**](https://www.idioms.online/blow-smoke-up-someones-ass/).  To fill someone up with flattery to get them to do something you want. This is especially common in sales.

Comment: Thanks, that's good, I'll accept it solution.